# Ubuntu Software is not working properly on 16.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 two days ago and the Ubuntu Software application works bad. Everytime I try to install any software, it stays installing forever without ending. Sometimes, after half an hour or so, I restart the computer and then the application is already installed, but sometimes it is not. For example, now I'm trying to install Shutter (in order to show you the error) and BleachBit but it just won't install. Other times I have to click twice on the "install" button but it asks me if I want to remove the software, because it was already installed... it's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The problems may occur for stale versions of software updater. Also with newer versions of `ubuntu` releases they release regular patches. current stable LTS version is `16.04.1` so you can try updating your system

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Add `sudo` prefix for super doer mode.

ubuntu community releases change summary for every patch release. You can get latest [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/16.04.1)

Comment: Thank you very much. When I run sudo apt-get update in the terminal, I get the following error

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

What can I do? I haven't opened any other applications

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I don't know how to correctly put the terminal results here :-/

Comment: got it ..It generally happens when there is some other application which has acquired the resources dpkg here ..

Comment: You can follow this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Thanks, radbrawler. The process to find out what's going on and how to fix it is very complicated. Do you think it is better to go ahead and install 16.04.1 from scratch?

Comment: Now that I am checking the version of Ubuntu I downloaded and installed, it is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS "Xenial Xerus"... Thus, I don't understand why I have this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48757/discussion-between-radbrawler-and-chuqui).